# accepts_nested_attributes_for not working as expected for User model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm getting the following error when trying to submit a nested attribute:

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: staff
```

My `User` model (created by Devise):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_one :staff
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :staff, reject_if: :new_record?
end
```

My Devise `registrations/edit.html.erb` view:

```
<%= f.fields_for resource.staff do |s| %>
  <%= s.label :notification_email %>
  <%= s.email_field :notification_email, placeholder: 'Enter notification email' %>
<% end %>
```

What gets submitted in the HTML post as a parameter:

```
"user"=>{"name"=>"Scott",
"staff"=>{"notification_email"=>"myemail@example.com"}}
```

I expected the HTML post parameter for staff to be `"staff_attributes"` rather than just `"staff"` based on the [documentation for nested attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).

Did I do something wrong? Do I really need to add `staff` to the `attr_accessible` list of attributes? Does this not work with Devise? I did have to use `resource` instead of `@user` in the view.

Comment: add staff_attribute in your attribute_accessible line -> attr_accessible :name, :staff_attribute

Comment: @RahulSingh, neither `:staff_attribute`, `staff_attributes`, `:staffs_attribute` and `staffs_attributes` worked when adding them to `attr_accessible` :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your view, remove `resource.` as following:

`<%= f.fields_for :staff do |s| %>`

in the model, add `:staff_attribute` (or `staff_attributes` not sure) to `attr_accessible`

Answer (score 0):

1. Pass in the symbol instead of an instance.
2. add `attr_accessible :staff_attributes` in the user model.
3. initialize the staff instance inside user controller's new method.

Comment: I didn't want to do #3 for my purposes, but otherwise this is correct. @Zakwan beat you by literally 1 second though!

Comment: In my code, without #3, the form with a new user will not render the field for staff correctly.

Comment: I don't display the `f.fields_for` if the user is not a staff member (and therefore doesn't have a `staff` attribute). In addition, I'm using Devise, so I don't even have access to the controller's `new` method.